# cxf response are not appended to logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j, cxf, slf4j

CXF responses are not getting logged in the log file although its displayed in the console.

Here is my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, theConsoleAppender, rollingFile, SYSLOG 
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %x %c{1}:%L- %m%n
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender.Threshold = debug

log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=${catalina.home}/logs/sequent-api-public.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.DatePattern='_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.rollingFile.Threshold = debug
log4j.appender.rollingFile.Append=true

log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.threshold=debug
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.syslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.facility=local6
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.facilityPrinting=false
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.conversionPattern=|%5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I am using log4j 1.2.17 and CXF version of 2.7.4, slf4j version of 1.6.1

What I really want to know is how the outgoing and incoming webservice requests are logged by cxf, do we need to set up interceptors for it?

-Thanks

Comment: I think you do need Interceptors. My [blog post](http://frvabe.blogspot.de/2014/02/logging-requestresponse-messages-with.html) may be useful for you.

Comment: @FrVaBe is not wrong. It's one way.